# wordpress check_password_reset_key not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a reset password for certain users and I do not want to call the standard WordPress form as it does not look good on the theme etc.

So the process is simple, the user clicks forgotten password, then input their email address. If the user is in the correct role, then call get_password_reset_key and send an email with key and email address to the user.

When the user clicks on the link to the email, I call `check_password_reset_key`  with the key and user login and it should work...

However, I keep getting the `WP_Error` etc.

So I created a really simple test and this still fails. I have googled lots and tried suggestions but still not about to get this working.

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['email_address'] );
echo "user_login = " . $user->user_login . "<br>";

$key = get_password_reset_key($user->user_login );
echo "key = $key<br>";          

$tmp =  check_password_reset_key($key, $user->user_login );
print_r($tmp);
```

// prints :

> WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_key] => Array ( [0] =>
>   Invalid key ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Comment: did you manage to find the answer? I'm getting this error and unable to find anything related

Comment: You are using the user login as the parameter to get_password_reset_key. The docs indicate the parameter should a WP_User object.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following once for detailed documentation,

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_password_reset_key/

What it says,

> This field is hashed after user clicks on link; old values are no
>   longer accepted.

So what happens, when user clicks on the link, before you can manipulate it, WordPress is already doing its task and that key is already expired when you have the key to use.

What you can do is either do all these process by your own generated key, or store the password_reset_key in user_meta and manipulate or use any actions related to forgot password or reset password.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/password_reset

Hope this one helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and maybe I didn't explain my test very well. I put the code into a separate little function and  therefore no user intervention.

Comment: I then copied the 'check_password_reset_key' function locally (called it 'check_password_reset_key99') and traced when things were going wrong and I think it's to do with :
$hash_is_correct = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword( $key, $pass_key );

my $wp_hasher does not have CheckPassword element and therefore $hash_is_correct is not set:
wp_hasher = PasswordHash Object ( [itoa64] => ./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz [iteration_count_log2] => 8 [portable_hashes] => 1 [random_state] => 0971c81c5b5e5303302903d42c925696 )

Clearly I am misunderstanding what is going on

Comment: I thought that 'check_password_reset_key' straight after 'get_password_reset_key' should not result in any error, as my understanding is get_password_reset_key creates the key and returns it and then the hashed version of the key with a timeout is added to 'user_activation_key'. Then when 'check_password_reset_key' is called with the key (not hashed) it would return is the key does not equal 'user_activation_key' but does when the key is hashed.